# Joining documents in Couchbase and using aggregate functions

Tags: mapreduce, couchbase, sql++

I have these 4 documents

Document 1

```
{
  "First_Name": "dhw",
  "Type": "GLAccount",
  "Acc_no": 1,
  "Last_Name": "irtahow"
}
```

Document 2

```
{
  "Marks": 13,
  "Type": "GLEntry",
  "Acc_no": 1
}
```

Document 3

```
{
  "Marks": 85,
  "Type": "GLEntry",
  "Acc_no": 1
}
```

Document 4

```
{
  "Marks": 93,
  "Type": "GLEntry",
  "Acc_no": 1
}
```

Now I want to use a sum function Documents 2,3 and 4 and then join it with Document 1. So the result of my query should be like

```
Acc_no First_Name   Last_Name      Sum(marks)

1       "dhw"       "irtahow"            191
```

So here you see I want to first sum all the marks of a particular Acc_No and then output its sum of marks and first name and last name.
I am able to sum the marks but not able to simulate the join.

EDIT 1:
This is what I have done so far

map function

```
function(doc, meta)
{

    emit(doc.No,doc.marks);
}
```

reduce function

```
_sum
```

I get sum  of all marks of a particular Acc No. but I am not able to join it with the document containing first name and last name

Comment: I assume all your documents are in the same bucket?

Comment: @user1697575 Yes. All are in the same bucket

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Added what I have done so far

Comment: If you use the value of Acc_no as the primary key of Document 1, you can use N1QL to achieve the sum and the JOIN.

Comment: No I dont want to use N1QL. It is very slow. Can it be achieved using views?

Comment: is it possible to redesign your json docs so that you'll have marks stored as an array in the GLAccount doc instead of having multiple docs?

Comment: I am trying to avoid that because for a particular account number I can have over 1 crore GLEntry docs and then having GLAccount information in GLEntry will only make redundant data. So I am trying to avoid repetition of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little hesitant to suggest this, because I'm not sure what the impact on performance of this might be, but this will get you the data in a single query.

Map Function:

```
function (doc) {
  var type = doc.Type == "GLAccount" ? 0 : 1;
  var marks =  doc.Marks ? doc.Marks: 0;
  var key = [doc.Acc_no, type];
  if (type === 0){
    key.push(doc.First_Name, doc.Last_Name);
  }
  emit(key, marks);
}
```

Reduce Function:

```
_sum
```

URL Query:

```
http://host:5984/db/_design/design/_view/view?group=true
```

Result:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":[1,0,"dhw","irtahow"],"value":0},
{"key":[1,1],"value":191}
]}
```

You would then need to extract the data from the JSON.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit your query. Like how are you emitting two rows even though you have a single emit function?

Comment: If you query the view with `?reduce=false` you will see the output from the map function. You get two rows in the reduce output because of the group level we selected.